# Is there a mySQL frontend that has an interface for joins?

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, phpmyadmin

Are there any mySQL frontends, like phpmyadmin, that has a graphical interface for joins?

I know you can run saved queries (which may include joins) in phpmyadmin, but I am looking for a user-friendly way of how other frontends are tackling the problem. I don't actually need a frontend, I just want to see how others are doing it.

If there are none are available, what would be a good way of approaching creating a join interface?

I am currently thinking, given a `student` and `enrollment` table (as a super simple example), such that

```
student table
+---------------------------+
| id   | name   | number    |
+------+--------+-----------+
| 2    | Joe    | 04567843  |
| 3    | Jim    | 43243254  |
| 4    | Jack   | 23145671  |
+------+--------+-----------+
```

and..

```
enrollment 
+---------------------+------------+-----------+
| id   | student_id   | course_id  | score     |
+------+--------------+------------+-----------+
| 1    | 2            | ma001      | 86%       |
| 2    | 2            | en001      | 46%       |
| 3    | 3            | ma001      | 78%       |
+------+--------------+------------+-----------+
```

The interface could allow you to select a primary table, and the fields you want, then a secondary table, and the fields you want. And finally, a JOIN fieldset, where you choose the join type and the fields connecting it (see image).

The image is a mockup using firebug manipulating phpmyadmin to show what I mean (hopefully)

[image]

I realise this is kind of 2 questions, but highly linked to each other, but to summarise, does a front end like this exist? And if not, would the above approach work?

Comment: I Dont see why it wouldnt work, but i think i would rather just type it and execute it. The only time this would save me any headaches is if i was doing a large multi table join (like 3+ tables) - just saying... Generally speaking, typing is always faster than an interface if you know what youre doing and in this case those that dont know enough to type probably arent going to know what a join is ;-)

Comment: @prodigitalson Yeah I totally understand what you're saying, I always type my queries, even simply ones (i.e. I don't use the Search tab in phpmyadmin) but I know the users won't be able to. One option is to allow the user to only choose between set type of reports, e.g. student report (only student table) and a student_enrollment report (student + enrollment). And each report type has a join linked to it, so with the above example, the student_enrollment report is defined as being a student join enrollment, even if they only select fields from the primary table.

Comment: well if this is for "end users" i think giving them an interface liek this would jsut be too confusing, unless they have a development or db type background. I think i would opt for only allowing prebuilt reports (ie predefined joins) but then allow them select a subset of data (ie. the actual `select` columns)

Comment: @proditialson Yeah I like that idea of predefined joins and prebuilt reports. It will probably end up going down that track. I always try to think 'flexible' first, then bring it back - I have an ideal that everything I build should be able to plug in to any hole - but in reality that is obviously never the case :)

Comment: If you want them to create joins maybe you should abstract that idea. I'm talking about using "Students" instead of "Students Table" and "Related data" instead of allowing them to choose join type. So it would be understandable for someone with little or no db background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to look at how others do it, play around with Microsoft Access a bit. e.g.
[image]

Comment: Thanks nos. There were a lot of good answers, but I already had Access on the computer - just never actually thought of using it for a source of inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of tools provide this feature nowadays

SQLYOG is what I use... though I rarely use their query builder...they have one which allows joins ...

DB Forge has the query builder with the join feature included too...
http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/
I was about to post the link to the query builder but this sites policy prohibits me from posting more than 2 links :(

Check out this link as it also has a screenshot included... smaller URL so have replace .'s for dot and /'s for slash

www dot activequerybuilder dot com slash screenshots.html

BTW MySQLs own tool which I feel is excellent also has this feature listed... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/query-browser/en/mysql-query-browser-using-graphicalbuilding.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how good it is, but this one claims to visually create joins:
http://www.cgiscriptshop.com/products/mdm/index.html

Right on the page it says:

```
Visually compose SELECT query, joining several tables.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [Navicat Premium](http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_premium/premium_overview.html). It has a '[Visual SQL Builder](http://www.navicat.com/images/stories/product/premium/product/en/mac_l/premium_builder_mac.jpg)' which sounds like what you're looking for.